# why do you have /home partition even you can't use it?

Tags: package-management, 14.10, disk-usage, installed-programs

I've set the `/` volume for 30gb and it's getting full now.
I want packages and programs to be installed in /home partition and I don't know how.

I want to install things into my `/home` partition!!

Comment: Packages are generally indtalled in /bin and /usr/bin. /home is just for personal files.

Answer (score 2):

A /home/ is intended for personal documents; not for software installation. Besides that not all computers are just by just 1 user and this saves a lot of space for all of us.

If you do want software installed in /home/ you can though: [install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) from [source](http://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/) and you can tell during compiling that installation directory should be something in /home/.

If your system is full with 30 Gb you should consider examining why. I never go over 15Gb and that is with apache and mysql and a fairly large database. Maybe there is something you never use that can be deleted.

Comment: Oh, thanks for reply I thought i've set the /home partition as 30gb but it was automatically set........ so it became 25gb and on my linux, leagueoflegends and nvidia graphic driver's installed and I think that's why please tell me if there's way to install in /home.....

Comment: also it says that I can't move files or folders into /home....